# Как совмещать БЭМ и React компоненты

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-native

Допустим есть два компонента `ProductList` и `ProductItem`

Если использовать `ProductList` как смарт-компонент и в нем выводить дамп-компонент `ProductList` через `this.props.map()`, то приходится использовать стили для блока `product-grid`

Код получается примерно такой:

```
//ProductList
render() {
            return (
                <div className="product-grid">
                    {this.props.products.map((productData,index)=>
                        <ProductItem key={index} data={productData}/>
                    )}
                </div>
            );
        }
```

Но в смарт-компонентах не должно быть указателей стилей.

```
    //ProductItem
<div className="product-card">
                    <div className="product-card__content">
                       <div className="product-card__content__attributes">
                        </div>
                            <img  className="product-card__content__image" src={this.props.data.image} alt=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Как протаскивать props с верхних компонентов, чтобы это не противоречило подходу Presentational and Container Components?

Comment: ProductList тоже можно сделать тупым, он будет принимать массив элементов. А над ним уже создать контейнер, который никак не будет связан стилями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart-компоненты (они же Containers) заводятся с одной единственной целью — достать данные из некоторого источника и передать их Dump-компонентам (они же Presentational компоненты) в подходящем для Dump-компонента виде. Т.е. они выполняют роль похожую на роль Presenter из [Model-View-Presenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter). Часто они даже не пишутся руками, а генерируются (см. `connect` в [React Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux)).

Если же ты придерживаешься этой парадигмы, но не используешь никаких библиотек, а пишешь все руками, то все должно выглядеть как-то так:

```js
class ProductListContainer extends Component {
  // ...
  render() {
    return <ProductList products={тут вы берете откуда-то данные} />;
  }
  // ...
}

class ProductList extends Component {
  // ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="product-grid">
        {this.props.products.map((productData,index)=>
          <ProductItem key={index} data={productData}/>
        )}
      </div>
     );
   }
   // ...
}

class ProductItem extends Component {
  // ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="product-card">
        <div className="product-card__content">
        // ...
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  // ...
}
```

Т.е. у тебя будет один Smart-компонент `ProductListContainer` и два Dump-компонента: `ProductList` и `ProductItem`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,
но все-таки не оставляет мысль , что это в некотором смысле это анти-паттерн - 3 разных компонента для одного простого блока.